# aws_boto3:listing contents of s3 path

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I need to list objects in s3 at a particular path (s3://<bucket_name>/folder1/folder2/). In this case only list objects that are available under **folder2**.

I am trying something below but not getting expected result. Please suggest how can I achieve this?

```
import boto3

bucket_name = "bucket_name"
key = "/folder1/folder2"

s3client = boto3.client('s3')
print(s3client.list_objects(Bucket=bucket_name, Marker=key)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [collections](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/collections.html) interface in boto3:

```
import boto3

bucket_name = "bucket_name"
key = "folder1/folder2" # do not need the first slash!

s3r = boto3.resource('s3')
print(list(s3r.Bucket(bucket_name).objects.filter(Prefix=key)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this?

```
s3client = boto3.client('s3')
print(s3client.list_objects(Bucket=bucket_name, Marker="/folder1/folder2/*")
```